# Is a single point topologically connected?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose a set $P$ is the union of $m$ separate curves in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $n$ individual points in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

When asked about the number of topologically connected components that $P$ has, is it correct to say that $P$ has $m+n$ topologically connected components?

It seems logical that one would describe each of the individual points as its own topologically connected component, but I'm not sure if this is rigorously correct.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, a singleton is connected, because it clearly cannot be partitioned into two disjoint nonempty sets.

Comment: What do you mean by "separated curves"? do you mean disjoint? And what about "individual points"?

Comment: Hopefully you are not using words like "connected" without a precise mathematical definition. Once you have that definition it is trivial to check whether a singleton (with its unique topology) is connected or not.

Comment: What is a "curve" to you?  Are the curves closed sets?  Are the curves and points all disjoint from each other?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^d$ is Hausdorff, which means that any two points may be separated by disjoint open sets. Therefore a collection of $n$ disjoint points is a collection of $n$ connected components.

However, take the topologist's sine curve $\{ (x, \frac{1}{x}) : x \in \mathbb{R}^{>0} \}$ together with the curve $\{ 0 \} \times [0, 1]$. These are "separate" in an informal sense - they don't intersect - but they're part of the same connected component. (In this instance, the curve is not closed. That may or may not be important to you.)